# Execute python-script via Url

Tags: python

Is it possible to execute a python-script on a server without using something like django?

I mean I put script.py on host.com and want to call it like this:

```
    http://www.host.com/script.py
```

The script then does something like calculating some variables and saving them on a mysql database.

edit: I assume I have to use something like cgi :-\

Comment: I wrote an answer to this once: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9382853/916657

Comment: using apache with webmin and virtualmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, yes. http://wiki.python.org/moin/CgiScripts. You'll have to either put your scripts in a cgi-bin folder or adjust the configuration for your web server.

Comment: well. how about just using a php-wrapper to call my script using exec. script.php -> exec("script.py")

Comment: @xMRW You would need to do ``exec("python script.py");`` at the very least, as python scripts are interpreted.

Comment: @xMRW You can do that, if you make your script executable (chmod +x filename.py on unix). However, Lattyware's solution is more portable (You can't make python scripts executable on windows) and probably the better one, especially if your site is hosted on someone else's server. Many server admins won't want you making your scripts executable, for security reasons. If it's your own server, and it's unix (or some derivative) either way works.